# Delayed awarding of Tumbleweed badge

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

I just went through the awarded Tumbleweed badges to check for any possible weed eater hat and stumbled over this question: [jQuery resizable plugin](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/100928/jquery-resizable-plugin)

The badge had been awarded 17 hours ago but the question is from 14th August 2015 which is clearly due to the needed range

> Asked a question with zero score, no answers, no comments, and low views for a week

so the badge should have been awarded long ago.

The same is true for [Creation of a list of 1000 items with Backbone](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/99183/creation-of-a-list-of-1000-items-with-backbone) which had been asked on 6th august 2015.

[image]

Comment: *Creation of a list of 1000 items with Backbone* has comments that were removed about 17 hours ago, which is likely the reason for that one. I can't see any reason for why *jQuery resizable plugin* wasn't "awarded" with Tumbleweed before though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. The author of [jQuery resizable plugin](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/100928/jquery-resizable-plugin) had their account merged with another yesterday. During a merge, the badges are moved over/re-awarded and they can appear with a different creation date as a result.
2. "no comments" is one of the requirements for the badge, so [Creation of a list of 1000 items with Backbone](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/99183/creation-of-a-list-of-1000-items-with-backbone) became eligible once the comments were deleted yesterday.

Comment: What about this one? http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5694/why-cant-i-define-this-symbol-in-masm

Comment: @SimonForsbergMcFeely The asker [undeleted it](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/5694/revisions).